# git push and fetch orphan branch

Tags: git

these steps are followed to replicate `repo1` to `repo2` using an intermediate `bare.git` without history

1. commit changes in `repo1`

```
repo1> git checkout --orphan tmp
repo1> git add .
repo1> git commit -m "keep single commit"
repo1> git branch -D master 
repo1> git branch -m master
repo1> git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now --all
repo1> git gc --prune=now
```

2. push from `repo1` to `bare.git`

```
repo1> git push --force <bare.git> master
bare.git> git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now --all
bare.git> git gc --prune=now
```

3. fetch from `bare.git` to `repo2`

```
repo2> git fetch --force <bare.git> master
repo2> git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD
repo2> git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now --all
repo2> git gc --prune=now
```

it works but instead of pushing and fetching only the changes, all the pack object is pushed/fetched! how to fix that?

Comment: Are you doing all of this locally, on one single filesystem?

Comment: @LeGEC I tried on the same machine and different machines and have the same results

Comment: I think that you if add repo2 as a remote of repo1 and push tmp after the commit on repo1, it should only push that single commit, and nothing else: `git push repo2 tmp:master` (or providing the URL to repo2, I do not think that makes a difference).

Comment: @eftshift0 in production `bare.git` is located on public server. `repo1` and `repo2` are located on different personal machines and cannot access each other.